# How to switch databases using AWS/RDS on a batch process and avoid downtime?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

For our internal usage, we have a web application on EC2 instance that reads (no writes) data from a RDS/Postgres db. During part of the day new data for this db is generated (batch process that runs for ~ 2 hours) and the data is written straight to the same database causing of course a downtime (~ 2hours) of the application until the data is totally written.

What could it be a good practice on AWS/EC2/RDS to manage a situation like this to grant no downtime to the application and also being able to roll back to the previous version and of course not switching to the new version if any error happens during the batch process?

Answer (score 0):

Typical ETL (Extract-Transform-Load) processes normally work by:

- **Loading** data into *Staging* tables
- Running scripts to **clean-up/transform** the content of the tables into a format suitable for reporting
- **Publishing** the tables for users to use

The last step can use a `TRUNCATE` then `SELECT INTO`.

If this is too much downtime, then another method is to have users query a **View**. Then, modify the view to point to the second set of tables (which now become the 'main' tables). So, each load, the View simply swaps between sets of tables.

Comment: The first option `truncate` is not viable for us for many reasons. The second idea of using `view` is better but it would require that the same db is used for read and write (heavily during the batch process with relative downtime due to scaling up the instance) so not practical.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using RDS snapshots for this. You would have a writable RDS "master" instance (or golden image, if you will) and you would have a refreshed read-only RDS instance that you query from.

An example process could look like this:

- Make sure that you have a CNAME alias record (via Route 53) setup in a hosted zone (with DNS resolution in the VPC enabled) to point to your current read-only RDS instance (to the name that you see in the RDS Console) - TTL of say 5-60 seconds
- Do the ETL/load to the master
- Perform any validation activities you need
- Snapshot the master RDS instance
- Spin up a new read-only RDS instance from the master snapshot
- Change the CNAME alias record to point to the new read-only RDS instance
- When all app database clients have failed over (see below) terminate the old read-only RDS instance
- Optionally [stop the master RDS instance to save cost](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_StopInstance.html) - until the next load

For this to work, you will need to use the CNAME for your app database connection pool settings and ensure that connections get aged out regularly - ideally a connection lifetime of no more than every few minutes in order to minimise the cut-over time. Also be mindful of DNS caching in some app runtimes. Historically, for instance Java would per default have some rather long-lived caching (that you can override).

You could automate this too. One option would be Codepipeline.

Your ability to "rollback" then depends on how many days back you retain snapshots for. To do the rollback you create an RDS instance from the given snapshot and change the CNAME.

Your other option could be using an [RDS Read Replica](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.html). But I am not sure if you can stop and (re)start the replication process for PostgreSQL - like for MySQL - during the period of load. And also I suspect that the replication to catch up could cause head aches (and perhaps some DDL statements don't replicate through gracefully or as intended either).