# Amazon RDS switch database after successful import

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

We want to serve a 40GB database (read only) to our web applications with Amazon RDS. This database needs to be periodically replaced by a newer version. In order to avoid downtime I think the best is to first import this update to another DB instance. When the new import is done without errors I want to switch to the newer database.

What would be the best way to manage this switching in AWS?

I've looked into Amazon RDS Proxy, but it looks like this is more for switching based on available resources. We just need to flip a "switch".

In [How to switch databases using AWS/RDS on a batch process and avoid downtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505430/how-to-switch-databases-using-aws-rds-on-a-batch-process-and-avoid-downtime) however the difference is the replacement of the entire database. a solution is provided to switch the DNS CNAME record. This looks like a slow solution since the DNS need to be propagated and could take time.

Comment: Not sure what is the issue. You change the endpoint in your clients to new database.

Comment: That is not possible. The application points to the same endpoint. The "database swap" has to be seamless without downtime.